# Require js not loading dependencies on time

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We're using require.js inhouse for the dependancy management of our app. Just recently I discovered something weird. I am defining a Module that extends from another which I'm including like so:

```
define(['core/view/v_Form'], function(v_Form){
        var v_ModalForm = v_Form.extend({
...
```

Sometimes, v_Form doesn't seem to load on time which is why Javascript throws an error as v_Form is not defined.

However, if I change it to this:

```
define(['order!core/view/v_Form'], function(v_Form){...
```

it works.

Shouldn't require.js just load its' dependencies before running the code, is this a bug?

Comment: Is v_Form a proper AMD module?

Comment: yes, otherwise it wouldn't be loading anyway...

Comment: Sometimes loading non AMD files as AMD files does cause inconsistent  issues, particularly with order so it would still load. In this example order should not be used with AMD modules, only with plain JS files. Also, !order has been deprecated in Require 2.0 and you should look into the shim config instead

Comment: thanks for letting me in on this.